# Derivation of CDF of the Geometric Series

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

According to this derivation the $\Pr(X>x)$ is the probability that the first $x$ trials were failures. Why is it not the probability that **at least** the first $x$ trials are failures? I understand that $(1-p)^x$ is the probability that the first $x$ attempts are all failures, however  if $X$ is the index of the first success and $X>x$ it does not neccessarily mean that the success occurs on the $x+1$ attempt, i.e the first $x+1$ trials could be failures and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event that the first $x$ trials are failures *is* the event that *at least* the first $x$ trials are failures.  That the first $x$ trials are failures says nothing about whether the $(x+1)$th trial was a failure or a success, because the trials are independent.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $X=k$ happens when the first $k-1$ are fails and the $k$th is success. So $X=k$ has probability $(1-p)^{k-1}p.$ If this is summed for $k=x+1,...$ to get probability that $X>x,$ then it's a geometric series with sum first term over (1 - ratio), where in this case the ratio is $(1-p).$

The calculation is 
$$ \frac{(1-p)^x\cdot p}{1-(1-p)}=(1-p)^x.$$
It can be looked at another way in that having the first success at $x+1$ or later is the same as having all fails during the first $x$ trials.